# Why is this callback undefined when I abstract my functions to named functions?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to understand the concept of javascript callbacks, and am changing this bit of (working) code that employs callbacks:

```
/* Working */

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    del  = require('del');

var cfg  = require(process.cwd() + '/config.json');

gulp.task('del:dist', function(cb) {
  del([cfg.path.dist], function(err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb();
  });
});
```

To code that uses named functions, so that I can better understand what's going on:

```
/* Not working */

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    del  = require('del');

var cfg  = require(process.cwd() + '/config.json');

gulp.task('del:dist', deleteFolder(cfg.path.dist, cb));

function deleteFolder(targetFolder, cb) {
  del(targetFolder, function doneDeleting(err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb();
  });
};
```

The problem is that the code with the named functions does not work. I get a `referenceError: cb is not defined` for `deleteFolder(cfg.path.dist, cb));`. Which makes sense, because it isn't. But it isn't defined in the working example either. So why does it work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback usually takes a function reference or an anonymous function as its argument.  The function executing the callback determines the parameters that are given to this function.

A function can be referenced using its function name without the parameters e.g. `deleteFolder`.  If you add the parentheses, then when that bit of code initially gets run it is evaluated and the return value of that function is passed to the `task` function, instead of the function itself being passed.

If you just passed it `deleteFolder` without parentheses it would callback with your function passing in `targetFolder` as its one and only argument (`cb` would be null inside your function).  The 'targetFolder' variable would contain what you would expect to find in `cb`.

The only value that the `task` function would pass into any callback function would be one argument (which here is labelled as `cb`).

Additionally you can't define a function such as 'doneDeleting' inside an argument.  You would need to define in separately and pass it by reference (as mentioned above).  However, as you are calling `cb()` from within it (and that is being passed in only when the callback is fired), you will need to pass the `doneDeleting` function as an anonymous function rather than naming it and passing it by reference, as `cb` would not be in the scope in which your function would be defined.

In your case the below will work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    del  = require('del');

var cfg  = require(process.cwd() + '/config.json');

gulp.task('del:dist', deleteFolder);

function deleteFolder(cb) {
  del([cfg.path.dist], function(err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb();
  });
};
```

I always wondered how you were supposed to know how many arguments a callback function would be passed. The answer is purely documentation, or failing that, trial and error / trawling the code.  Basically, the arguments for a callback function aren't up to you!

Think of it this way.  Often, the point of a callback is do something after a function has run with some new data that has been generated by that function.  After the function has finished we want to do something with that data.  The way we get that data is by passing by the function creating the data, passing it in to our argument where we can then manipulate it.  If we passed in our own arguments then we would perhaps never have access to the data being gernerated by the function.

It would be good for you to have a look at what a callback function is in a bit more detal - [here](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) is a good place to start (it uses callbacks at the end of AJAX requests).

Comment: Kelsaditas answer doesn't work. However, using a named function does work if I just pass the function without parentheses (but then I can't pass any arguments of my own). What I don't understand is why passing it an anonymous function *does* work when I use parentheses and explicitly declare the `cb` parameter. What's the difference? The only difference I can see is the naming.

Comment: @109830487515325 apologies I misread Kelsadita's answer.  I've rewritten how you would need to do it in my answer.

Comment: I've found that it does work when I wrap `deleteFolder` with an anonymous function and then pass the callback to `deleteFolder`. That allows me to still use deleteFolder. But what I still don't understand is why I have to specify the `cb` parameter with an anonymous function, but not with a named function?

Comment: Because the callback will **always** be passed 1 argument inside the `task` function (somewhere in the gulp code).  We have defined `deleteFolder` to take just 1 argument (to match up with the 1 argument we have found out that gulp will give it).  If we allowed `deleteFolder` to take two arguments it would still only be passed one argument by gulp's `task` function.

Comment: I understand that it works like that for `deleteFolder`, but I don't see why an anonymous function would have to specify the `cb` parameter in the `gulp.task` call, when a named function doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: Ah ok, so basically an anonymous function doesn't have its "function signature" laid out anywhere else in the environment.  Even though the task function may want to pass it one argument, it can still potentially accept zero (or two).  This may be fine as it may not need the data from the `task` function anyway so it runs, oblivious to any arguments, completely fine.  Essentially the anonymous function still has to determine how many parameters it will take; much like a named function.

Comment: Is it because: if I define the anonymous function without a `cb` parameter, gulp cannot pass its callback logic to that function, since I've not given it a parameter to put it? And that doesn't apply to a named function because gulp.task can decide for itself which parameters it uses to initialize that function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61338/discussion-between-richieahb-and-109830487515325).

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
gulp.task('del:dist', deleteFolder(cfg.path.dist, cb));
```

you are not passing `gulp.task` a callback. You are invoking the function `deleteFolder` and passing it's return value. Since it returns nothing, the return value of that function is `undefined`. Therefore you see the error.

Comment: You mean that gulp.task sees the `cfg.path.dist` object as the callback function? Would it work if I just switch them around?

Comment: @109830487515325 No, the `gulp.task` looks at it's second argument and expects it to be a function. It is not a function in your case, you are calling a function there which means, the return value of the function will be the thing seen by `gulp.task`

Comment: Ah ok. Now I understand.

Answer (score -1):

The callback function of `gulp.task` takes only one argument. So the named function you are using will have only one argument.

Correct version is as follows,

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
del  = require('del');
var cfg  = require(process.cwd() + '/config.json');

gulp.task('del:dist', deleteFolder);

function deleteFolder(cb) {
  del([cfg.path.dist], function doneDeleting(err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb();
  });
};
```

Comment: @109830487515325 why -1 ? Will like to know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry, I didn't downvote you. No idea why you're being downvoted.. Or were downvoted.

Comment: Though I can see that you've moved my `cfg.path.dist` variable, which makes the function rather pointless. The only reason I abstracted it into a function is because I wanted the target to be variable, and you've made the target static. So that might be why..

Comment: Also, I've tested it and it doesn't work. Still returns undefined for `cb` in `deleteFolder(cb)`. So maybe that as well. But I agree that downvoting without a comment isn't nice.

Comment: Understood what I was doing wrong, updated the answer